# Mail function not working on live server

Tags: php, html, email, gmail

Please help me. I am new in PHP. My mail function is not working even on live server. I don't know whats wrong with my code.

```
<div class="contact-form">
            <h4>Get in Touch</h4>
            <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
                <div class="col-md-6 form-left">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 form-right">
                    <input class="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                    <input class="" type="text" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" required="">
                    <textarea class="" placeholder="Message" name="message" required=""></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" >
            </form>
        </div>
```

And here is my mail function file. name send_form_email.php.

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "ali.gohar@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $name . " " . $email . " " . $phone . "wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];


    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";

    }
?>
```

Comment: @john Conde Can you please give me the link of existing answere if you can't guide me here.Thanks

Comment: ^^^ Look at the top of your question

Comment: This condition `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` is never met.

Comment: So what should be the possible solution. @Akintunde Olawale

Comment: add name attribute to the submit button. Change this  `<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" >` to `<input name="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" >`. Check the duplicate at the top of the question too. Also google "how to send mail in php". THere are soo many tutorials with free code snippets that you can modify easily.

Comment: Thanks so much.Its working now. thanks alot.